# Function that accesses Class's property

Tags: vb.net

I have a class where I add some folder paths and give them unique IDs. 
I can access my function using `item.DeleteFolder(item.FolderID)`
What I want is to able to do the following:

```
item.FolderID.DeleteFolder()
```

What is the way to do this?

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
' Simple business object. A FolderId is used to identify the type of Folder  
' but the Folder name can change.  
Public Class FoldersBackup
Implements IEquatable(Of FoldersBackup)

Private m_FolderPath As String
Public Property FolderPath() As String
    Get
        Return m_FolderPath
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_FolderPath = value
    End Set
End Property

Private m_FolderId As Integer
Public Property FolderID() As Integer
    Get
        Return m_FolderId
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        m_FolderId = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Function DeleteFolder(FolderPath As String) As Boolean
    If FolderPath Is Nothing Then
        Return False
    End If
    System.IO.Directory.Delete(FolderPath)
    Return True

End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'd have to change the type of m_FolderId to a new class you create. it would have to be like this:

```
Public Class FoldersId

Private m_FolderPath As String
Private m_FolderId As Integer

Public Sub New(Optional ByVal path As String = "",Optional ByVal Id as Integer = 0)
    m_FolderId = Id
    m_FolderPath = path
End Sub

Public Property Value() As Integer
    Get
        Return m_FolderId 
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        m_FolderId = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Function DeleteFolder() As Boolean
    If m_FolderPath Is Nothing Then
        Return False
    End If
    System.IO.Directory.Delete(m_FolderPath)
    Return True

End Function

End Class
```

and then, change your class to something like this:

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
' Simple business object. A FolderId is used to identify the type of Folder  
' but the Folder name can change.  
Public Class FoldersBackup
Implements IEquatable(Of FoldersBackup)

Public FolderID As New FoldersId()

Private m_FolderPath As String
Public Property FolderPath() As String
    Get
        Return m_FolderPath 
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_FolderPath = value
        FolderID = New FoldersId(value,FolderID.Value)
    End Set
End Property

End Class
```

that way, you'd be able to call the method like this:

```
item.FolderID.DeleteFolder()
```

but if you want to get the id value, you have to get it like this now:

```
item.FolderID.Value
```

Comment: i see it now that you want to call it from FolderId, but the concept is the same

Comment: Is it possible to implement it in the same class?

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Class FoldersBackup
    Implements IEquatable(Of FoldersBackup)

    Public Property FolderPath() As String
    Public Property FolderID() As Integer

    Public Function DeleteFolder() As Boolean
        System.IO.Directory.Delete(Me.FolderPath)
        Return True
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: With this the only option I have when I type "oFB.FolderID." is .ToString. The DeleteFolder does not appear.

Comment: Because you need to type `oFB.DeleteFolder`.

Comment: My solution above can do that as well. What I want is to be able to have an option in VS when i type to have both oFB.FolderID.DeleteFolder and oFB.FolderID.ToString

Comment: @nectarines You solution above cannot do this because it is effectively a `shared` function not declared as such, and it expects a parameter. A member function does not need a parameter. In order to be able to call `DeleteFolder` on `FolderID` (which is an `Integer`), you need to declare an [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx) for `Integer`. You don't want to do this.